# In Euchre, can you call a misdeal with "No ace, no face, no trump"?

Tags: euchre

In the game of Euchre I have been dealt a hand of nines and tens, none of which are trump.  May I declare a misdeal?  I have seen some groups play that the hand is redealt by the same dealer while other groups pass the dealer.  Is this an official rule or just a "house" rule?

Comment: Are you saying that it called a misdeal after trump is called?

Comment: Yes only after trump is made therefore all nines and tens with no trump. Some people play  as a misdeal and no points awarded and goes to next dealer Yet others play as a redeal of the same dealer.

Comment: I edited the question and voted to re-open. While it's still not clear to me what *exactly* you're asking, I'm sure that you'll find an answer in [this wikipedia article about FARMER'S HAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euchre_variations#Farmer's_hand)

Answer (score 7):

This is a house rule.  I have seen it played in informal games, but never among serious players.  Once, I saw a person try to declare "ace, no face" in a $5 game.  Since this person shared information about their hand it was ruled that they should be bumped and forfeit 2 points even though no cards had been played.  All of the spectators and other players agreed with this decision, including the player's partner.  The person who declared "ace, no face" was told not to do that again.

Comment: Agreed, “Ace, no face” is nonsense, but “No Ace, No face, No trump“ is kinda like getting a hole in One, or a 10-7 split. It’s an event, a celebration and a prize should be awarded, and that prize is a re-deal. I’ve been playing Euchre forever. How often have I seen this hand happen? Twice – and I was one of those 2 lucky contestants. Give whomever a little rise for being able to dump an awful hand and get on with life. Put all the cards back and the dealer re-deals. My rule is final for I am the Euchre King and I can do anything.